# Question in analysis

Tags: analysis

How to prove this excerise  about limit therome

Suppose that $X_n\to a$ and $c$ is real number. Prove that
 $cX_n \to ca$.

For given any $\varepsilon >0$ ,there exist $n_1$  such that 
$|X_{n} - a|<\varepsilon$, for all $n \geq n_1, -\varepsilon < X_n-a<\varepsilon$

Multiplying  by  $c$,

$$-c\varepsilon < cX_n-a < c \varepsilon$$

$$|cX_n-ac|< c \varepsilon$$

Choose $\varepsilon=\varepsilon/c$ ,  $c \ne 0$

$$|cX_n-ac|<\varepsilon$$

$$cX_n\to ca$$

This  is my soulution. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** what is the definition of $x_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$? Write it out then multiply a certain inequality through by a constant $c$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c=0$ then $cx_n \equiv 0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and the result is trivial. If $c \neq 0$, since $x_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ then given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$, if $n\geq N$. Notice that $$|cx_n-ac|=|c|\cdot |x_n-a|<|c|\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}=\varepsilon.$$ This proves the claim.